# Merge validation summary in single line(All required validation in single line,All invalid field validation in single line etc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, client-side-validation

I am creating one ASP.NET MVC Application using JQuery,KnockOutJs etc.
I have one model for SignUp and use client side validation only.

```
public class SignUp
    {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.UserNameIsRequired, AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.UserNameLength, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages))]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z ]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.OnlyAlphabetsAndSpaceAreAllowed)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\s*[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})[ ]*$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.InvalidEmail)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.EmailIsRequired, AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.EmailLength, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages))]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.PasswordRange, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages),MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages), ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.PasswordRequired, AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceName = MessagesConst.InvalidConfirmPassword, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages))]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public bool IsNewsLetter { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I m showing validation summary on view.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmRegistration" }))
    { 
        <div class="msg">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">@UserResource.lblSignUp</h1>
        <div class="content_box signup">
            <div class="sign_up">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="/" title="Home">
                                                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="feat_text">
                        <h1>@LayoutResources.tglnCF</h1>
                        <p class="subtitle">@LayoutResources.tglnSubTitleCF</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bottom_box">
                        <strong>@UserResource.lblAlreadyAccountOnSocialnetwork</strong><br>
                        <span class="sing_in_direct"><a href="/Login">@UserResource.lblSignIn</a> directly from here.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">

                    @*Remove Placeholders for validation issue.*@

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="blue">@UserResource.lblUserName</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @data_bind = "value:UserName, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']", placeholder = Placeholders.UserName, want_live_validation = true })
                            <span class="help-inline">
                                <span class="sprite"></span>
                            </span>
                            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="blue">@UserResource.lblEmail</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @data_bind = "value:Email, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']", placeholder = Placeholders.Email, want_live_validation = true })
                            <span class="help-inline">
                                <span class="sprite"></span>
                            </span>
                            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="blue">@UserResource.lblPassword</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @data_bind = "value:Password, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']", title = ToolTipResources.ttPassword, placeholder = Placeholders.Password, @class = "tooltip", want_live_validation = true })
                            <span class="help-inline">
                                <span class="sprite"></span>
                            </span>
                            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)*@
                            <div class="m-t5">
                                <div data-bind="css:PasswordStrengthClass()"></div>
                                <span id='result' data-bind="text:PasswordStrengthMessage()"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="blue">@UserResource.lblConfirmPassword</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @data_bind = "value:ConfirmPassword, valueUpdate:['afterkeydown','propertychange','input']", placeholder = Placeholders.ConfirmPassword, want_live_validation = true })
                            <span class="help-inline">
                                <span class="sprite"></span>
                            </span>
                            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)*@
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <label class="checkbox blue" for="checkbox1">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNewsLetter, new { name = "check1", id = "checkTermAndPolicy" })
                        @UserResource.lblDiscoverNewProjectWithWeeklyNewsLetter
                    </label>
                    <p class="terms_text">
                        @UserResource.lblBySignInYouAgreeToOur <a href="/Terms/TermsOfUse.html" target="_blank">@UserResource.lblTermsOfUse</a> @UserResource.lblAnd <a href="/Terms/PrivacyPolicy.html" target="_blank">@UserResource.lblPrivacyPolicy</a>.
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <p class="errorMassage"></p>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="SIGN UP">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

currently summary appear like 
[image]
but i want to customize that summary like all validation that fire for required field will show like(User Name,Email,Password Required.)
or all validation that fire for invalid field will show like(invalid email address User Name,Email.)

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: @Liam OK let me clear this in image u can see two required validations are fired now i want to merge them in single line like User name,Password are required.

Answer (score 1):

You could try @Html.ValidationSummary().ToString().Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")

I'm not sure how validationsummary spits out its linebreaks, however, so you can probably find out and cut that down.

Comment: but i don't want to round trip of server.

Comment: Inline c# code is executed on the server and passed to the view (no extra round trips), so this would be carried out on the server, and the result of this operation (i.e. your validation summary without linebreaks) would be sent to the view.